# Pygame, making an animation happen whenever a key down event happens

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to get the animation to happen once the RIGHT arrow key is press and only then.  i have tried putting the looping "currentimage" variable in the if statement, but nothign seems to work.  i wanted to then set a boolean to to be true when the key is pressed but for some reason later on (even in the same loop??) nothing triggers it?  How can I get the animation to work when I have the right arrow key pressed down?  Here is my code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,720))

pygame.display.set_caption("Window")

x,y=0,0
movex, movey = 0, 0
animation_boy = 0


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image=pygame.image.load("images/10.png").convert_alpha()
image2=pygame.image.load("images/10(3).png").convert_alpha()
image=pygame.transform.scale(image, (93, 262))
image2=pygame.transform.scale(image2, (93, 262))

currentimage = 1
animation_boy=False

gameLoop=True
while gameLoop:

    mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):

            gameLoop=False

        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

                movex = 3
                animation_boy=True

            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

                movex = -3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

                movey = -3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):

                movey = 3


        if (event.type==pygame.KEYUP):

            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

                movex = 0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

                movex = 0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

                movey = 0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):

                movey = 0

    window.fill((0,0,0))

    x+=movex
    y+=movey


    window.blit(image2, (x,y))

    if (animation_boy==True):

        if (currentimage <= 25):

            window.blit(image2, (x,y))


        elif (currentimage >= 25 ) and (currentimage <= 50):

            window.blit(image, (x,y))

        else:

            currentimage=1

    clock.tick(50)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: At the end of the loop, try setting `animation_boy = False` so that for each time that it loops it will only set `animation_boy` to be `True` if the key is pressed.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, below, rather than editing the question. [This is perfectly welcome here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Right so the variable `currentimage` is never updated in your loop and in the block:

```
if (animation_boy==True):
    if (currentimage <= 25):
        window.blit(image2, (x,y))
    elif (currentimage >= 25 ) and (currentimage <= 50):
        window.blit(image, (x,y))
    else:
        currentimage = 1
```

The only operation that is executed all the time is the `window.blit(image2,(x,y))` which is your default image as well.